# How to use subquery in position X in SELECT X FROM ... with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Given the following table in database

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE phones (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  user_id INTEGER, 
  phone VARCHAR, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
)

CREATE TABLE emails (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  user_id INTEGER, 
  email VARCHAR, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
)
```

And I want to know how many emails and phone numbers each user have.

And the following query works:

```sql
SELECT
  users.id AS id,
  users.name AS name,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM emails WHERE emails.user_id = users.id
  ) AS email_count,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM phones WHERE phones.user_id = users.id
  ) AS phone_count
FROM users;
```

But when SQLAlchemy generates query like this:

```sql
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.name,
  email_count.count_1,
  phone_count.count_2
FROM
  users,
  (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_1
    FROM emails, users
    WHERE emails.user_id = users.id
  ) AS email_count,
  (
    SELECT count(*) AS count_2 
    FROM phones, users
    WHERE phones.user_id = users.id
  ) AS phone_count
```

I tried to user GROUP BY and join them, but since some user does not has both email and telephone, they're excluded, and I don't like NULL in OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Updated SQL:

```
select e.id, e.name, distinct_email, distinct_phone
from
(
   select u.id, u.name, count(distinct e.id) as distinct_email
   from users as u
   left join emails as e
   on u.id = e.user_id
   group by u.id, u.name
) AS e
full outer join
(
   select u.id, u.name, count(distinct p.id) as distinct_phone
   from users as u
   left join phones as p
   on u.id = p.user_id
   group by u.id,  u.name
) AS p
on e.id = p.id
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but... not perfect. maybe you want to add DISTINCT to COUNT. But what if the table does not have a unique constraint? I would use this if I have only one to count.